# JSON processing in Android

Tags: php, android, json, listactivity

```
[{"ip":"127.31.25.145"},{"ip":"196.32.25.256"},{"ip":"10.32.25.256"}]
```

This a JSON response I get from a php webpage I developed. Now I want to add all values under `ip` field to a `ListActivity`. I tried a lot but could do, there are many references out there but even then I couldn't do. This JSON response may contain many more `ip` values. Its kind of a variable response, gets changed from time to time. Please Help!!!

Comment: Share what you've tried so we can spot the errors.

Comment: did you try the suggestion in my post??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
JSONArray mJsonArray = new JSONArray("Response");
for(int i=0;i< mJsonArray.length();i++)
{
    JSONObject obj =(JSONObject) mJsonArray.get(i);
    String strIp = obj.getString("ip");
    arraylist.add(strIP); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have the json downloaded.

You need to parse the json first.

```
[ // json array node
    {  // json object node 
        "ip": "127.31.25.145"
    },
```

To parse

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(); // to add ip's
JSONArray jr = new JSONArray("json string");
for(int i=0;i<jr.length();i++)
{
    JSONObject jb =(JSONObject)jr.get(i);
    String ip = jb.getString("ip");
    list.add(ip); 
}
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,list);
//this refers to activity context
// android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 is the layout from android framework with a textview
// http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.1_r1/frameworks/base/core/res/res/layout/simple_list_item_1.xml?av=f
// the third param is your list
```

Since its a `ListActivity` to display items

```
setListAdapter(adapter);
```